# Как мне сделать так, чтобы при указании паролей в переменной password_1, в терминале выводилось столько паролей, сколько указали?

Tags: python, list

````
password_1 = int(input('Введите количество паролей: '))
password_length = int(input('Введите длину паролей: '))
password_2 = input('Нажмите Enter для генерации паролей: ')

if password_2 == "":
            for x in range(password_length):
                password_2 = password_2 + random.choice(list('123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'))
            print(password_2)```
````

Comment: Зациклить код генерации паролей на количество `password_1`: `for _ in range(password_1):` и внутри цикла код генерации пароля

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

password_1 = int(input('Введите количество паролей: '))
password_length = int(input('Введите длину паролей: '))
password_2 = input('Нажмите Enter для генерации паролей: ')


if password_2 == "":
    for x in range(password_length):
        password_2 = ''.join([random.choice(list('123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM')) for x in range(password_length)])
        print(password_2)
```